# Increment an attribute in postgresql function

Tags: database, postgresql, function, datatables

Below is my function for inserting values in a table .. However i want the numofexisting attribute to be an increasing number so as to be unique .. how can I make it happen ?

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_CourseRun()
    RETURNS VOID AS
    $$
    DECLARE curr_sem integer;
    DECLARE curr_season semester_season_type;
    DECLARE curr_year smallint ;
    DECLARE numofexisting integer;
    BEGIN
        numofexisting := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM public."courserun") + 1 ;
        curr_sem := (SELECT s.semester_id FROM "semester" as s WHERE s.semester_status = 'present');
        if (curr_sem % 2 = 0) then 
            curr_season = 'spring';
            curr_year = curr_sem /2;
        else
            curr_season = 'winter';
            curr_year = (curr_sem+1) /2;
        end if;

        INSERT INTO public."courserun"  
        SELECT c.course_code, numofexisting, 5, 5, 2, curr_sem, labcode_for_course(c.course_code)
        FROM "Course" as c
        WHERE c.typical_season= curr_season and c.typical_year = curr_year;
    END;
    $$
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
```

Comment: Declare it to be `serial` in the table definition.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Is this the only way ?

Comment: No, but the simplest and best. Or use a sequence explicitly.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe What is the sequence explicitly ? i cant use this way cause i 've already made my data base and the attribute i want to be serial is a primary key ..

Comment: I have added an answer that contains instructions how to use a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Create a sequence:

```
/* instead of 42, use a value larger than the current maximim value */
CREATE SEQUENCE courserun_seq START 42;
```

Then insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO courserun (..., numofexisting, ...)
   VALUES (..., nextval('courserun_seq'), ...);
```

This would assume that *all* inserts into the tabe are done this way.

You can also change the table to automatically use a default value:

```
ALTER TABLE courserun
   ALTER numofexisting SET DEFAULT nextval('courserun_seq');
```

Then you can either omit the column in the `INSERT` column list or use the value `DEFAULT` like this:

```
INSERT INTO courserun (..., numofexisting, ...)
   VALUES (..., DEFAULT, ...);
```